# /assigning values in a wire method showing undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a simple wire methods which fetch a list of records. In this method, I'm trying to assign a boolean variable as false based on returned data but seems like the assignment in not happening.

**js Code below:**

```
 @track emptyCauseRec;

@wire(getCauseRecords, {reId: '$riskcausedetailrecord'})
    causeRecords(wireResult){
        const { data, error } = wireResult;
        this.wiredCauseData = wireResult;
        if(data){
            this.causerecs = data;
           // this.emptyCauseRec=false;
            console.log('causerecs:::'+JSON.stringify(this.causerecs));
            this.error = undefined;
            //Check cause rec empty
            if(this.causerecs == [] || this.causerecs== null){
            this.emptyCauseRec=true;
        }
        }
        else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.causerecs = undefined;
        }
        
        console.log('emptyCauseRec:::'+this.emptyCauseRec);
    }
```

**this.causerecs == []**, but this.emptyCauseRec says undefined.

[image]

If I initially assign a value as this.emptyCauseRec=false, it always stays false. Where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check cause rec empty
if(this.causerecs == [] || this.causerecs== null){
```

This condition will never be true, because `if(data)` checks for null already, and `someVar == []` will always be false. See:

```
let a = [];
let b = [];
if(a == b) {
  console.log('This message will never print');
}
```

This is because `a` and `b` are two instances of an Array, and the `==` in this case simply asks if the two Arrays are the same instance, which would never be true.

Compare to:

```
let a = [];
let b = a;
if(a == b) {
  console.log('This will always print');
}
```

The typical way to check if an Array is empty is to check `.length`:

```
this.emptyCauseRec = !data.length;
```

Here, we'll set `emptyCauseRec` to false if `data.length` is not 0, or true if it is 0. Note that the line of code above eliminates the need for an if statement; the emptyCauseRec will be set or reset correctly each time the wire method is called with data.